# iOS XCode sudden console spam: [default] IOConnectCallMethod (kIOHIDEventServiceFastPathUserClientCopyEvent): 0xe00002f0 (copySpec = (null))

Tags: ios, xcode, arkit

I have an ARKit iOS app that was working fine, **the phone suffered a pretty hard drop**, and this morning it's not capturing frames, instead it spams the console with:

```
[default] IOConnectCallMethod (kIOHIDEventServiceFastPathUserClientCopyEvent): 0xe00002f0 (copySpec = (null))
CVDataBuffer contains an invalid header
```

**What does this error represent?**

PS. Checked another AR app - also does not work with ARKit

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Device reboot has fixed the issue, I hope this is a permanent solution.